# Automating the Android build process

Tags: android, build-process, build-automation

**I want a command line tool that works in the following situation:**

1) A computer with JDK and Android SDK installed (with the target Android platform).

2) An Android project created using eclipse.

**And give me the following output:**

1) The signed APK of the given eclipse Android project.

How do I accomplish the above by writing a Java program (By kicking off Ant using the Java Runtime class)? I want to automate the build process, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I think, and repeat I think, that is not accomplished with a java programm. you need an ant script

Comment: Yes, it is done through Ant but how does does the build process work? So that I can try running the Ant script using the Runtime class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) to automate `beta` and `production` releases. Fastlane is largely written in Ruby and you can customize releases based on your internal processes. You can watch this [Droidcon '16](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs9qDcx5nSAhWJo48KHR0rDaQQtwIIGzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1Yg98k-MuQo&usg=AFQjCNEJ6l69AmzAfUSAi1fbHG6ZExVszw&sig2=CceDJl6PEjjhUTsPbL9a2A) video to get started.

Answer (score 4):

I've used **ant** to do this and we use **Jenkins** for Continuous Integration. I've written a post on how to automate this.

http://www.multunus.com/2011/09/continuous-delivery-for-android-apps-part-1/

Answer (score 2):

I use Maven with the Android plugin.  It works well.

See http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/.

Comment: I want to build a command line tool to do that. Not eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

The Android build process is fairly complex: quite a few tools are invoked one after another: javac to compile, then dx to convert to dex, then aapt to package (I'm sure missing a few). You can run Ant in debug mode to see the exact sequence (it is also documented, somewhere...). 
So you can either:

1. Bundle the Ant jars with your app and invoke Ant programatically
2. Write a Java 'script' that invokes the tools in the correct order
3. Write a simple shell script/batch file and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolay, I just found the solution as well.

Comment: Hi Ragunath, Kindly share the solution, or link. I am using Android Studio on MAC and want to automate build with script.

Comment: @RagunathJawahar Please share your solution here as well to bring this post to a closure. Thanks.

Comment: @Perry I don't remember what I did back then. But now I use Fastlane. You can check my answer from the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42314655/421372